# susy sass mixin error

Tags: sass, gulp, susy

I have set up susy sass and gulp using this tutorial: https://zellwk.com/blog/gulp-libsass-with-susy/  I cannot use any mixin like @include span(12 of 16); as it always throws an error like:
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: sass\framework_header.scss
Error: no mixin named span

```
   Backtrace:
    sass/framework/_header.scss:4
    on line 4 of sass/framework/_header.scss
```

> > ```
> >     @include span(12 of 16);
> > ```
> >
> > -----------------^

```
at options.error (C:\bitbucket\encore\themes\encore\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Realised why am getting this error.  Susy 3 is installed on my system and I didn't know that all of the the susy @include etc have now changed.  so instead of @include span(12 of 16) it is something like width: span(3);